# Powershell: how to filter out specific text?

Tags: powershell

I need to export a Windows Security event log to a CSV file for fast auditing of deleted files.  I just need specific lines of information in my CSV fle, particularly within the "Message" field.  My command below:

```
Get-EventLog "Security" -before 4/10/2013 -InstanceId 4663 | select-object Index,TimeGenerated,Message | export-csv c:\export.csv
```

Output looks like:

```
Index         : 244336
TimeGenerated : 4/9/2013 6:06:33 PM
Message       : An attempt was made to access an object.

            Subject:
                Security ID:        S-0-0-00-0000000-0000000-000000
            37-1111
                Account Name:        joeblow
                Account Domain:        contoso
                Logon ID:        0x888210

            Object:
                Object Server:    Security
                Object Type:    File
                Object Name:    C:\files\Important_doc.xls

                Handle ID:    0x2178

            Process Information:
                Process ID:    0x4
                Process Name:    

            Access Request Information:
                Accesses:    %%1537

                Access Mask:    0x10000
```

All I need are the Index, TimeGenerated, Message->accountname, and Message->object->objectname, and Message->object type. How do I filter it out so it looks like something below, or something clean enough in a CSV to view in Excel?

```
Index         : 244336
TimeGenerated : 4/9/2013 6:06:33 PM
Account name  : joeblow
Object type   : File
Object Name   : c:\files\Important_doc.xls
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a lab to test that entry with now, but try this:

```
Get-EventLog "Security" -before 4/10/2013 -InstanceId 4663 | % {
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Index = $_.Index
        TimeGenerated = $_.TimeGenerated
        "Account Name" = $_.ReplacementStrings[1]
        "Object Type" = $_.ReplacementStrings[5]
        "Object Name" = $_.ReplacementStrings[6]
    }
} | export-csv c:\export.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

In an `EventLogEntry`-object, there's a property `ReplacementStrings` that usually contains all the variables used in the message, in the order that they're show in the text. The first variable in that message is the "Security ID", so that's most likely stored in `$_.ReplacementStrings[0]` since arrays start at zero. So just count your way down.